# Monitoring multiple ubuntu servers bandwidth

Tags: network-monitoring

I have 30 ubuntu 20.04 and i need to monitor the bandwidth of all of them at the same time , is there any easy way to do this without installing apache or database on all of them?

Currently im keeping all of them open through SSH and monitoring their bandwidth with nload

Answer (score 2):

Install a network monitoring system that suits your need.

Typically the monitoring systems can grab statistics either via an agent installed on the server, or via standard means such as SNMP.

[Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/) is one such system. It's free software, and available in Ubuntu repositories, and can fetch data via either SNMP or a dedicated agent.

With this you can also collect information via SNMP from systems such as routers and switches, and thus get an idea of what links in your network see high load, and what does not.